# Minimum value of function with 3 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the minimum value of $\dfrac{x^4+y^4+z^2}{xyz}$?

I tried to use am, gm inequality but that didnt get me anywhere. 
I also thought abt Differentiating but am not exactly sure how that would work with 3 variables

Comment: local minimum, or absolute minimum in a given region, or ...

Comment: Is $x,y,z$ real numbers? If it is, there is no global minimum since for $x = -y = 1$ the ratio tends to $-\infty$ when $z \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non negative $x,y,z$

$$\dfrac{x^4+y^4+z^2/2+z^2/2}4\ge\sqrt[4]{x^4y^4\cdots}$$

Comment: Thanks... That got me the answer